# Change DataSource with each user

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

Good afternoon,

When i create a DataSource It asks for credentials and saves it to app.config:

```
<add name="XXXXXCS" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=XXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But I need to change the User and Password depending on who logs in to the app.
This is because the server has restriccions to each user and they need to log in to SQL with their respective credentials.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for your help!

-------------EDIT-----------

I know how to get the connection string from app.config,
what i don't know is how to asign it to the data source.

This is what i have been using:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(xxxxxx).ConnectionString

Using myConn = New SqlConnection(CadenaConexion)
    myConn.Open()
    Using comm As New SqlCommand("QUERY xxxx", myConn)
            Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(comm)
            Dim table As New DataTable
            adapter.Fill(table)
        dgv1.DataSource = table
    End Using
    myConn.Close()
End Using
```

but now that i want to change to bindings how do i actualy change the datasource connection string?

Comment: You can store the default connection string in the config file, either with or without credentials. In code, read the default connection string into a connection string builder, set the user credentials, get the new connection string from the builder and pass that to your connection object. Look into the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class to help with that.

Comment: Thanks jmcilhinney, i edited my question so it's clearer.

Comment: I told you exactly what to do. Currently, you're getting the connection string from the config file and passing it to the connection object. As I already told you, pass that connection string to a connection string builder, set the appropriate properties, get the new connection string and pass that to the connection.

Comment: Thank you I am changing the connection string in the table adapter like this: `Me.TableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString()` in every adapter but i wanted to be able to do that directly to the data source so i didn't have to do it in every adapter.

Comment: In order for that to happen, you'd have to change the code of the table adapter classes. You can certainly add a partial class to add or change some behaviour but whether or not there would be a way to change the default behaviour for setting the connection string, I don't know. You could, for instance, add a constructor that allowed to you to specify whether to use the default connection string or use user-provided credentials and then use that constructor instead of the default. You'd then built the functionality I described into that constructor.

Comment: I guess another option might be to define your own class that inherited the table adapter and then you can write your own parameterless constructor that would set the `.Connection.ConnectionString` property. That way, you can use your class wherever you're currently using the table adapter class and it will just work. That's probably not superior to the previous option unless you genuinely need a parameterless constructor. That would be the case if you were adding table adapters to forms in the designer, but I'd recommend against that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use connection string

```
Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=XXX;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=True
```

Comment: This won't work for someone logging in with an SQL Server user account, which appears to be the case (but not completely clear by the OP).

Comment: actualy this pinted me in the right dierection. i ended up saving the connection strings in the app.config file and made and if statement when they chose the user to select the correct one

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) to dynamically build connection strings.

```
        Dim builder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder()

    builder.ConnectionString =
        "server=(local);user id=defultID;" &
        "password=defultPassword;initial catalog=AdventureWorks"
    builder.UserID = "newuser"
    builder.Password = "newPassword"
```

Comment: Thanks Jiachen Li-MSFT, i edited my question so it's clearer.

Comment: Do you mean using [BindingSource Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to encapsulates the data source?